# FreeSwitch - MongoDB integration

Tags: freeswitch

I've installed FreeSwitch on Linux CentOS 6.4 server. I found out that if I want to add a user, I need to make a xml file under /freeswitch/conf/directory/default folder. I was wondering why it doesn't use database to manage account and password?

FreeSwitch supports MongoDB CDR Mod. http://wiki.freeswitch.org/wiki/Mod_cdr_mongodb It shows detailed call record on web browser. It is like admin tool. However, this is not what I was looking for.

I am looking for a way to store new account and password into MongoDB and use it when a user make a call through FreeSwitch. So, I can handle user data in a better way. Does anyone know how to solve my problem? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the fastest way for you to get familiar with FreeSWITCH is to read the book: http://www.packtpub.com/freeswitch-1-2/book

The book is quite short, and it answers most of potential questions, and for the rest of questions you have the Wiki and the source code :)

to answer your question, yes, there's a number of mechanisms to look up external sources for user information and credentials. The simplest one is to use mod_xml_curl: it requests pieces of XML from an HTTP server, and you can build the service with whatever database backend you prefer.

Comment: FreeSwitch supports ODBC type database. http://wiki.freeswitch.org/wiki/Using_ODBC_in_the_core

Comment: Do I really have to use mod_xml_curl to use MongoDB?

Comment: I found out good article. http://saevolgo.blogspot.kr/2012/07/freeswitch-with-sip-users-in-mysql-mod.html It explain how mod_mxl_curl works. :) Thank you.

Comment: ODBC can be used as alternative to sqlite for storing FreeSWITCH'es internal state, like user registrations, and other stuff. For user credentials, you need to use mod_xml_curl. That guy with the blog is actually in my skype contacts :)

Answer (score 0):

Freeswitch supports sqlite, pgsql and odbc those three way all can solve you problem .In **sip_profiles/internal.xml** you can find some way to connect database

```
<!--<param name="odbc-dsn" value="dsn:user:pass"/>-->
<!-- Or, if you have PGSQL support, you can use that -->
<!--<param name="odbc-dsn" value="pgsql://hostaddr=127.0.0.1 dbname=freeswitch user=freeswitch password='' options='-c client_min_messages=NOTICE' application_name='freeswitch'" />--> ##
```